# JodaTime parser crashes on America/Bahia_Banderas timezone

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timezone, jodatime

implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.10.6"

Sending a `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseDateTime("00:00")` call works with most timezones but the `America/Bahia_Banderas` time zone causes a crash.

````
Cannot parse "00:00": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (America/Bahia_Banderas)
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis (DateTimeParserBucket.java:473)
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis (DateTimeParserBucket.java:411)
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime (DateTimeFormatter.java:928)```

Should this be filed as and issue or am I doing it wrong?
````